# How to determine whether a DOJO Checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: javascript, syntax, dojo

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" value="test" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox">
```

How to check above dojo checkbox is checked or not in my javaScript function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use javascript function checked over id, like:

```
 if (test.checked == 1){
          alert("checked") ;
    }
else{
          alert("unchecked") ;
    }
```

**Here .checked will return "1" in case the checkbox is checked.**
Please try this in your javascript and let me know in case of any concern.

Comment: Personally I would use the widget code to test if a dijit checkbox is checked or not. (I'm supposing you're using the plain HTML/DOM approach). But the widget code is almost the same. (I'm **not** the downvoter btw).

Comment: Yes, widget approach is the better one Dimit but more or less same.

Comment: Indeed, it's just doing the same thing behind the screen. I upvoted your answer btw (to remove the negative score).

Answer (score 13):

You can check this in various ways. You can use plain HTML/DOM/JavaScript and use something like:

```
if (document.getElementById("test").checked) { ... }
```

or with Dojo:

```
if (dojo.byId("test").checked) { ... }
```

This is what @Shreyos Adikari meant I think but you can also use the widget itself (which is doing the same thing behind the screens) with:

```
if (dijit.byId("test").checked) { ... }
```

The difference between the first two methods and the last one, is that the first two use DOM nodes, while the last one uses the Dojo CheckBox widget/object which has a similar property.
I personally recommend the last one, because this should **always** work, even if they decide to change their template.

But anyhow, there are plenty of examples on the web about how to achieve this (even on the Dojo documentation itself), I recommend you to view the [API Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/form/CheckBox.html) or at least the [examples](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/CheckBox.html).